# Como puedo hacer que el boton HOME en la derecha pero en linea con el logo

Tags: html, css

Estoy empezando un poco con el HTML y CSS pero no logro conseguir que el botón home quede en linea con el logo y que no este subrayado, ya trate de utilizar weight y talvez pensé que al poner el código en la misma área del banner podría estar alineado con el logo pero hasta el momento nada funciona y sigue apareciendo de esa manera, hasta el solo he logrado alinearlo a la derecha que es como planeaba y que este haga la accion de regresar a la pagina de inicio pero al tratar de alinearlo con el logo para que se vea mas presentable no he encontrado quizas la respuesta es mas sencilla de lo que parece, espero me puedan disculpar

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');
* {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ffc65c;
}
.menu{
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Palanquin Dark", sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
 }
.banner{
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/m51kNMY/Logo-Max-without-background-2-15.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    background: #684815;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.navegation{
    width: 100%;
}
#btn-menu{
    display: none;
}
#mmovil{
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    text-align: right;
    color: #edbc65;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Home.css">
        <title>pruebas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navegation bar-->
    <header id="banner">
        <section class="section home" id="p-inicio"></section>
            <div class="banner">
            <img id="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/p49TsP8/Logo-Max-without-background-1-5.png" alt="BLogo">
            <input type="checkbox"  id="btn-menu">
            <label for="btn-menu" class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="mmovil"></label>
                <div class="menu"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/Index.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-brain"></i>HOME</a></div>
        </div>  
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar la propiedad `display:flex` a la clase banner. Alinear los elementos dejando el espacio en medio y alinearlos en el eje `y` al centro.

```
.banner{
    /* ... */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:center;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');
* {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ffc65c;
}
.menu{
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Palanquin Dark", sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
 }
.banner{
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/m51kNMY/Logo-Max-without-background-2-15.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    background: #684815;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:center;
}
.navegation{
    width: 100%;
}
#btn-menu{
    display: none;
}
#mmovil{
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    text-align: right;
    color: #edbc65;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Home.css">
        <title>pruebas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navegation bar-->
    <header id="banner">
        <section class="section home" id="p-inicio"></section>
            <div class="banner">
            <img id="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/p49TsP8/Logo-Max-without-background-1-5.png" alt="BLogo">
            <input type="checkbox"  id="btn-menu">
            <label for="btn-menu" class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="mmovil"></label>
            <div class="menu"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/Index.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-brain"></i>HOME</a></div>
        </div>  
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Si funciono solo que ahora el logo esta en la derecha y el boton home a la izquierda, hay alguna forma de intercambiarlos de posicion?

Comment: No sé por qué lo ves en ese orden. No deberían cambiarse de lugar https://jsfiddle.net/gtby024x/